# Vertical lines with dates are not created on Python Dash Plotly

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a Python Dash app where I try to create a plot. First, I create a line where `x` values are dates and `y` values are integers. Then I try to add a few vertical lines in specific dates. The outcome figure includes only the first line and none of the vertical lines. I have a feeling that something is wrong with the date formatting, but I haven't been able to pinpoint it.

This is my callback code:

```
def update_plot_and_table():
    df_1 = create_df1()
    
#Line chart creation
    figure = {
        'data': [{'x': df_1['Date'], 'y': df_1['value_col'], 'type': 'line'}],
        'layout': {
            'xaxis': {'title': 'Date'},
            'yaxis': {'title': 'Value', 'range': [0, 10]}
        }
    }

    vertical_lines = []
    df_2 = create_df2()
    for index, row in df_2.iterrows():
        the_date = row['Date']
        if not pd.isnull(the_date):  # Check for valid date
            vertical_lines.append({
                'type': 'line',
                'x0': the_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
                'x1': the_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
                'y0': 0,
                'y1': 9,
                'line': {'color': 'red', 'width': 2, 'dash': 'dash'},
            })
    figure['data'].extend(vertical_lines) 

    print(f"Figure data: {figure['data']}")

    return figure
```

The `figure['data']` looks like this:

```
Figure data: [{'x': 0   2023-10-17
1   2023-10-18
2   2023-10-19
3   2023-10-20
4   2023-10-21
5   2023-10-22
6   2023-10-23
7   2023-10-24
8   2023-10-25
9   2023-10-26
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns], 'y': 0    4.763087
1    4.693306
2    4.626573
3    4.562784
4    4.502365
5    4.444668
6    4.389595
7    4.337048
8    4.253622
9    4.173468
Name: value_col, dtype: float64, 'type': 'line'}, {'type': 'line', 'x0': '2023-10-22', 'x1': '2023-10-22', 'y0': 0, 'y1': 9, 'line': {'color': 'red', 'width': 2, 'dash': 'dash'}}]
```

Comment: The dtype of your x data is datetime, but you are using a string for `x0` and `x1`. Try converting to datetime instead of using strings, or convert your x data to strings. There's an example in the docs ([Highlighting Time Series Regions with Rectangle Shapes](https://plotly.com/python/shapes/)).